Ubuntu 24.04: codes in Netbeans files disappeared?
I've really been stuck in a jam for a whole week with this problem.
reason: I used VMware to create an Ubuntu virtual machine (Ubuntu 24.04 - the one with crown background), then I installed netbeans for studying JavaOOP but the problem is
"All my codes are invisible in Netbeans"
+I've tried all versions of Netbeans 12.3, 21, 22, so I think this is not a version problem.

I also tried 'View' -> then 'show non-printable characters'
I tried 'Window' -> then 'reset windows'
I even tried change the font and background color but i seemed not worked.

If anyone used has faced this problem or have any possible way then please show me, I can't bear this anymore.!!
The problem is in the picture you guys can see it more clearly!
invisible characters Netbeans

Have you checked the Netbeans site to see what versions of Ubuntu they support.

I can not find any info on using Netbeans on Ubuntu newer then Ubuntu 20.04 Suggest you do some research.

I checked the Apache Netbeans site, almost every version of netbeans  have their own linux Netbeans versions.
